# How can I create a button that makes new Object as previous one in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, frame

I want to create a button that makes a new image. But this new image should be the same as the first one (`bild`).

I also tried to see what is working with `print` command.
The console shows all the prints but nothing more happens when I click the button. The new image is not appearing in the app.

I don't have any more ideas about that problem.

```
@IBOutlet weak var bild: UIImageView!

@IBAction func NewImage_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    let newImage = UIImageView(frame: bild.frame)
    print("0")

    let newY = bild.frame.origin.y + 40.0
    print("1")

    newImage.frame.origin.y = newY
    print("2")

    self.view.addSubview(newImage)
    print("3")
}
```

Comment: `newImage.image = bild.image`

Comment: Also I suggest you think harder about your variable names. A UIImageView is not an  image (or a `bild`). It is an image _view_ (`bilderrahmen` perhaps).

Comment: Thank you! and yes, I have to think about it :)

Comment: If the problem was trivially solved, accept an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the missing line is

```
newImage.image = bild.image
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to set an image to it for see it, second you don't need to add it to view again: so here is working:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bild: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
@IBAction func NewImage_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    let newImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: bild.frame.origin.x, y: bild.frame.origin.y + 40, width: bild.frame.width, height: bild.frame.height))
    newImage.image = UIImage(named:"Your image name")
 }
```